# Can we include a variables "TOTAL_SUM" in the detail band in ireport?

Tags: jasper-reports

i have a requirement where i want to display the total sum of a field "A" in another field "B"
IE if field "A" consist 5 records with values

```
1. 2
2. 2
3. 2
4. 2
5. 2
```

i used a variable to get the sum of field "A" 2+2+2+2+2=10
i want the total sum IE "10" to be displayed in field "B" all 5 records
but if i use that variable in field "B" it gives me results like

```
1. 2
2. 4
3. 6
4. 8
5. 10
```

which is not what i require

so can i achieve it in detail band in i report?

Comment: Jasper cannot make a sum of all bands when all bands have not been rendered (it doesn't yet know what's in next bands). Consider computing this sum appart and pass it as a report parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `evaluationTime="Report"` for the text field B.